# what is correct? either of both parties, or either or both parties

Tags: grammar

my problem is trying to find out what is the correct phrase between a)either of both parties shall report to us the new discovery,  and, b) either or both parties shall report to us the new discovery

Answer (score 1):

The phrases do not mean the same thing and without context it is impossible to be completely certain which meaning is intended, but it is likely that it is the former (using *of*). This isn't a very natural phrasing. It would be more common to simply say "either party".

Either OF both means that *either* A *OR* B is acceptable/expected.

Either OR both means that there are three acceptable/expected options: A or B or A+B.

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in whether both parties can report or not. (a) implies that only one party will report (although "either party shall report to us the new discovery" sounds more natural and is the one that I have heard used, whereas I have never heard the addition of "of both" to the statement). (b) implies the possibility of both parties reporting the discovery although it could still be one.